# Django RF, How to pass user instance for object creation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest framework+React JS, uses session authentication.

When explicitly I pass `user id` in POST request, it saves in database.

```
let data = { product: 11, quantity: 1, user: 1 };
```

When remove the `user id` it fails to save and gives error,

```
let data = { product: 11, quantity: 1 };
```

How can I mitigate the error ? ie,I want the view function to add the `user` id instead of sending it with POST data.

models.py

```
    class Cart(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
```

The POST function in React

```
 let data = { product: 11, quantity: 1, user: 1 };
    const endpoint = "/api/CartCreate/11/1/";
    apiService(endpoint, "POST", data) 

//note: api service is like axios with csrftoken
```

view

```
class CartCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CartSerializer
    queryset = Cart.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = self.request.user
        pk = self.kwargs.get("pk")
        product = Product.objects.get(pk=pk)
        quantity = self.kwargs.get("quantity")
        serializer.save(user=user, product=product,quantity=quantity)
```

The screenshot of error as below

[image]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What is the given error? does is_authenticated returns true or false?

Comment: I have updated the question with error, please check,@ArakkalAbu @Ramy M. Mousa

Comment: @RamyM.Mousa the error is I am missing user id in the post function, If I pass { product: 11, quantity: 1, user: 1 } as data in POST request it successfully create object. but if it is { product: 11, quantity: 1}, then it fails, however in production scenario I wont be able to add user id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created another view and added user ID with incoming data

```
 class CartCreateApi(APIView):
        def post(self, request, format=None):
    
            data = request.data
            data['user'] = request.user.id
    
            serializer = CartSerializer(data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```